# Segmentation fault using i/o stream

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to solve a high school problem and I get segmentation fault
when I try to debug my program. Could you tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

void afisare_cifre(int a[30],int n)
{
 int nr=0,cp;
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
    cp=a[i];
    while(cp!=0)
    {
       if((cp%10)%2==0)
         nr++;
       cp/=10;
    }
    fout<<nr<<" ";
    nr=0;
 }
    fout<<"\n";
 }

  int main ()
 {

   fin.open("in.txt", ios::in);
   fout.open("out.txt", ios::out);
   int n,p,k,a[30],ok=0;

   if(fin.bad())
   {
    cerr<<"Eroare!"<<endl;
    exit(1);
   }
  if(fout.bad())
  {
    cerr<<"Eroare!"<<endl;
    exit(1);
  }
    fin>>n>>p>>k;
    n = std::max(0,std::min(n, 30));
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     fin>>a[i];

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    if(a[i] % p == k)
       fout<<a[i]<<" ";

 fout<<"\n";
 afisare_cifre(a,n);

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
      if(a[i]==a[j])
          ok=1;
  if(ok)
    fout<<"ELEMENTELE NU SUNT DISTINCTE";
  else
    fout<<"ELEMENTELE SUNT DISTINCTE";

 return 0;
}
```

I thought it may be a memory problem, but I can't figure it out.Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of n?  Can n exceed 100?

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger, but 'for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)' doesn't look right if you are using i as an array index.  Indices start at 0 and the last valid index, in your case, is 99.

Comment: You're passing `"Atestat.*", ios::*` into the constructor and again when you call `open`.

Comment: No, n can't exceed 100, and it seems that the problem is with this : if(a[i] % p == k) f_out<<a[i]<<" "; 
@MartinJames Yes, but I don't think it would affect something just because I started the index from 1. However, I have modified the index to start from 0 and that's not the problem. The breakpoint is at the line I just mentioned.

Comment: @ViorelD If your `n` is 100 then `i` will be 100 with `i <= n` as the loop condition. And if your array's size is 100 then `a[i]` will try to access outside the array boundary, because `a[99]` is the last element, not `a[100]`.

Comment: @zenith I've noticed and as I said, I have modified the Index to start from 0 and the line is looking now like : for(int i=0;i<n;i++) and I'm still getting the segmentation fault.

Comment: @ViorelD Arrays start at index 0, not 1.  I won't be the least bit surprised if the segmentation fault is due to you improperly faking 1-based arrays in C++.

Comment: @ViorelD Oh okay excellent. Can you update the code snippet to reflect your changes?

Comment: @zenith I have modified my code and I still get the error. I have written another version of the code without the i/o stream and it works perfectly. I just can't figure out why..Btw, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing wrong with your code is that you wrote your code assuming that arrays start at index 1 instead of 0 and that your loops do not properly limit themselves to the highest index (99) for your `a` array.

To address the second issue, your input uses a variable `n`, but nothing stops anyone from entering a totally out-of-bounds value for `n`.  You can stop this by allowing any value to be entered, but limit how many times to loop:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
f_in >> n >> p >> k;
n = std::max(0,std::min(n, 100));
```

The above makes sure that n is at least 0, but no more than 100.

Next, change your loops to start from 0.  I know that others may disagree that writing 1-based array loops is ok, but in my experience, I have yet to see (novice) coders write bug-free code that attempts 1-based array access.  There is usually an "off-by-1" error somewhere in the code, and these errors are very difficult to find.  This is especially the case if the coder isn't consistent and introduces 0-based indexing somewhere in a large program, conflicting with the 1-based indexing used somewhere else in the program.

So for example, instead of things like this (which will not work due to an out-of-bounds access):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    f_in >> a[i];
```

do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    f_in >> a[i];
```

Making these changes *may* solve your segmentation fault.  I didn't go through all of your code, but these are the obvious issues.

Also, make sure that you are using good values by either using a debugger, or using `cout` to display the input values before they're used.  You have a line like this in your code:

```
    if (a[i] % p == k)
```

and if `p` is 0, then taking the modulo of 0 is undefined.

The other possible issue is stream related.  You have global variables as streams, so you should try and manage them differently and see if that alleviates the segmentation fault issue you're having.

First this:

```
ifstream fin("Atestat.in", ios::in);
ofstream fout("Atestat.out", ios::out);
```

Should be:

```
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;
```

And inside of `main`, open the files there:

```
f_in.open("Atestat.in", ios::in);
f_out.open("Atestat.out", ios::out);
```

If the segmentation fault occurs when main() returns, then it is an issue with the closing of the streams (which is automatic due to the destructor of the stream objects being called).  This shouldn't occur, but something you should be aware to if this doesn't correct the segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I have modified my code and I'm still getting the segmentation fault. I must add that I have written another version of the code without the i/o stream and it is working perfectly. I just can't figure the segmentation fault here.

Comment: Then you should show the data you're using for n, p, and k.  As a matter of fact, you should `cout` those values to confirm they are being read correctly (and that `p` is not 0).

Comment: You shouldn't have changed the original code, as my answer now doesn't match with what you had done.  Instead, make an edit to your code to add another code block with the changed code.  Second, I updated my answer to address the modulus issue, and to try and manage your streams differently.

Comment: Thank you so much!It seems it was a i/o related problem, thanks for pointing that out. I still have so much to learn..